# Saving a cache object when a WCF webservice is ended

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a simple WCF webservice with 2 methods : one save/updates an obect in the cache and the other one deletes it. How can I save the object when I close the webservice server.

Using `CacheItemRemovedCallback` doesn't work because the object is removed everytime i update it.
Using `Global.asax.cs.Application_End()` doesn't work also because the cache is cleared by the time it get here.
Using `Dispose()` method method doesn't work because it get called every time a call has finished.

```
[ServiceContract]
public class WebService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public void Test(string message)
    {
        List<string> Logs;

        Logs = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("LogMessages") as List<string>;
        if (Logs == null)
        {
            Logs = new List<string>();
            Logs.Add(message);
        }
        else Logs.Add(message);

        HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("LogMessages", Logs, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, null);
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public void WriteToFile()
    {
        List<string> Logs;

        Logs = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get("LogMessages") as List<string>;
        if (Logs == null)
        {
            string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_fff");
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                //any method of writing the object to disk
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("LogMessages");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if you need to do something when a WCF service starts or stops it should be done by [extending the `ServiceHostFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702697.aspx).

Check [`ServiceHost`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) `OnClose` or `OnClosing` event to do what your need.

```
public class DerivedHost : ServiceHost
{
   public DerivedHost( Type t, params Uri baseAddresses ) :
      base( t, baseAddresses ) {}

   protected override void OnClose(System.TimeSpan timeout)
   {
       ...

       base.OnClose(timeout);
   }

   protected override void OnClosing()
   {
       ...

       base.OnClosing();
   }
}
```

You can also implement your own [instance provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iinstanceprovider.aspx) and use the `ReleaseInstance` method.

```
public class MyInstanceProviderBehavior : IInstanceProvider
{

  ...

  #region IInstanceProvider Members    

  public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
  {
     ...
  }

  #endregion
}
```

For more information about WCF extensibility, take a look at [Carlos Figueira blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/tags/wcf/).